# Add Rails Ajax EDIT Form In Bootstrap Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, modal-dialog

I am trying to put a "new category" form in a Bootstrap modal in my Rails 4 app.  I've tried to implement the systems from [here](http://coderwall.com/p/ej0mhg/open-a-rails-form-with-twitter-bootstrap-modals) and [here](http://github.com/sunwooz/modal-form), but I'm stuck.  Ideally, I'd like to add the category, close the modal and have the new category automatically append to the current list of categories. Currently, I can't get the form to load in the modal using jQuery.

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <ul id='categories'>
    <%= render partial: @categories.order(title: :asc) %>
  </ul>
</div>        

<%= render 'category_modal' %>
```

**_category.html.erb**

```
<li> 
  <%= category.title %>      
  <%= link_to 'EDIT', edit_category_path(category) ,  class: 'btn btn-xs btn-warning pull-right', remote: true %>
</li>
```

**_category_modal.html.erb**

```
<div class= "modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="ajaxModal"  >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div id='content' class='modal-content'>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_edit_category.html.erb**

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default  btn-xs pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" >
    Cancel
  </button>
  <h2> EDIT CATEGORY </h2>           
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-body-content">
        <%= render 'form' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [@category] , remote: true do |f|  %>
  <div class="panel-body" >
      <div class="form-group" >

      <%= f.input :title, label: 'Category Title',  focus: true, id: 'category_title' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >

     <%= f.button :submit, value: 'SAVE CHANGES  ', :class => 'btn btn-info btn-md ' %>
      </div>
    <hr>
    <%if @categories.present? %>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <h4>
          Existing Catgegories
        </h4>

        <div class="row" >

         <% @categories.order(title: :asc).each do |category| %>

                <%= category.title %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
$("#ajaxModal").modal("show")
$('#content').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'edit_category', :object => @category) %>");
```

**categories_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @categories = Category.all.order(title: :asc)
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @categories }
    end
  end



def edit
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end

def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update_attributes(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to(categories_path, :notice => 'Category was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @category.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Dmitriy Dudkin's [really elegant solution here.](http://www.jetthoughts.com/blog/tech/2014/08/27/5-steps-to-add-remote-modals-to-your-rails-app.html) The way he does it, you don't have to include the modal on each page...just call it programatically.  It's awesome.